# html link to display dropdown list

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, hyperlink, dropbox

I need a link eg "Add" (Not button). And every single time the user click on the add link, this following drop down list will appear.

```
    <select name="dropdown">
        <option value="a">Apple</option>
        <option value="b">Bee</option>
        <option value="c">Cat</option>
        <option value="d">Donkey</option>
        <option value="e">Elephant</option>
    </select>
```

The maximum amount of the "Add" link the user should be able to click is 5 times. So if example the user click on the "Add" link 3 times, there should be 3 drop down box.
It has to be on the same html page. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!.

Comment: So you want the same menu to appear three times on a single page? Will the markup be identical? How will you differentiate between each dropdown menu when the form is submitted (presuming they're part of a form...)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In general, it is a good idea to show what you have tried here.

Comment: The page should have one dropdown list with Add(out of the drop box) at the bottom, and whenever the user click on the Add, another identical dropdown list should appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascrtipt/jquery for manipulating with controls.
Here is raw sample how it can be done:

```
$(function() {
    $('#add').click(function() {
        $(this).before($('select:eq(0)').clone());
      if ($('select').length > 5) $(this).hide();        
    });
});​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fhqAt/1/

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, but how do I refer to the script from the Add link? <a href ????> Add </a>

Comment: You just have to set the id of your `<a>` tag to  "add", like this: `<a href="#" id="add">link</a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

         $("#add").click(function(e){
            var selectbox = $("select:first").clone();
            $("select:last").after(selectbox);

            if ($("select").length >= 5) 
                $(this).hide();
          });

  });
```